# What do the icons in Windows Disk Management mean?

Tags: windows, disk-management

i have ***three*** hard drives (and one DVD-ROM drive) in my Windows Server 2003 machine:

[image]

For some reason, Windows Disk Management seems to think i have four hard disks (and one DVD-ROM drive).

The drive that contains my valid volumes is marked as

> Missing Offline, with an `X` icon

The new phantom disk is marked as:

> Offline, with a *do not enter* icon.

What do the icons in Windows Disk Management mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4b6d9afa-0e0d-4afb-a42f-00c1154cb379.aspx) will tell you what the things such as "offline" and "missing" will mean, but it will not tell you what the icons are (I can't find that information after looking) - they're most likely just a little feature that makes the item/error easier to remember.